# running nginx as a reverse proxy with apache

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, cache

Q1) Do I need mod_deflate running on apache? does it help in performance in anyway?

Q2) Do I need mod_cache running on apache if nginx is serving a static caching proxy?

```
<IfModule mod_cache.c>
CacheEnable disk http://website.com/
CacheIgnoreNoLastMod On
CacheMaxExpire 86400
CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.1
CacheStoreNoStore Off
CacheStorePrivate On
<IfModule mod_disk_cache.c>
CacheDefaultExpire 3600
CacheDirLength 3
CacheDirLevels 2
CacheMaxFileSize 640000
CacheMinFileSize 1
CacheRoot /opt/apicache
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to run mod_deflate on apache, use compression of nginx instead. Secondly you can use caching of nginx instead of mod_cache on apache.

You can read up using the link below to get a better idea of nginx caching.

[How to set up Nginx as a caching reverse proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy)

Comment: but an off question... wouldn't mod_deflate/cache running increase the performance of content passed to nginx?

Answer (score 0):

If Nginx was doing gzip compression on the client's incoming connection, I would guess that the overhead of compression in Apache just to get the response back to Nginx would outweigh, or at least cancel out any gain.