# how to install nginx as reverse proxy with apache?

Tags: nginx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [running nginx as a reverse proxy with apache](https://serverfault.com/questions/224813/running-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache)

how to install nginx as reverse proxy with apache ? 
in kloxo panel 
need full tutorial

Comment: Please try to search? This is a duplicate of the first 10 related links to the right. I also _know_ you were shown a big red warning of possible duplicates when you asked this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need use ssh to install nginx.

1. Enable EPEL:

   rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/$(uname -m)/epel-release-5-3.noarch.rpm
2. Install nginx:

   yum install nginx
3. Change Listen in Apache2:

   Listen 127.0.0.1:80
4. Configure nginx:

example:

```
 server {
    listen IP:80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
    location ~* \.(jpg|gif|png|css|js)$ {
    root /var/www/example.com/;
    }
 }
```

Comment: tried domain not working