# A web server or caching proxy to cache php completely as html?

Tags: web-server, cache, html, opcode

My Server's load and mysql usage are higher than usual and recently I see about 350 processes for each HTTPd and mysqld.

Is there a web server or caching proxy to cache PHP as HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use nginx as reverse proxy with cache ability. There was a discussion about this, [check it here](https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy)

Comment: +1 Thanks, Does this method still interacts with database?

Comment: It is your web server that interacts with database. nginx in this case is a web proxy. If you explain your scenario in details maybe me or someone else will be able to help you little more.

Comment: What about using mysql query caching? Check the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-cache.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to configure MySQL with Query Caching and see the results.