# Nginx cache entire site while performing MySQL maintenance

Tags: mysql, nginx, wordpress, cache

I currently have a high traffic WordPress site that is entirely static. But it currently generates each page via the MySQL database anyway (I know I should be caching content).

I will be moving the database to another server which will take about 20 minutes and I would like a cached version to be displayed while the MySQL server is unavailable.

It this easy to achieve using Nginx alone?

Comment: What do you mean Varnish doesn't support HTTPS?

Comment: I may have mis-understood some of the Varnish documentation. Removed that from my post.

Comment: Why are you going to have downtime? This is easy to accomplish without any downtime at all using replication.

Answer (score 1):

yes, ist easy;

- [setup proxy_cache](https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy) with cache_time ~ 24hrs [(off.docs)](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_cache)
- run wget over your site (generate a cached version of each page)
- make your maintainance
- after this, change cache_time to something like 5min or 1 hour

Comment: Could you go more in-depth on the wget portion of this?