# SirTunnel (python script) vs already exist https server (node.js) is it possible

Tags: tunneling

I found https://github.com/anderspitman/SirTunnel

This is usage:

```
How do you use it?
If you have:

A SirTunnel server instance listening on port 443 of example.com.
A copy of the sirtunnel.py script available on the PATH of the server.
An SSH server running on port 22 of example.com.
A webserver running on port 8080 of your laptop.
And you run the following command on your laptop:

ssh -tR 9001:localhost:8080 example.com sirtunnel.py sub1.example.com 9001
Now any requests to https://sub1.example.com will be proxied to your local webserver.
```

Because i already use port 443 with my webserver on Node.js i not sure who to make it works together.

Any suggestion ?

Comment: this is why you should consider to use a reverse proxy like nginx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up Nginx as a caching reverse proxy?](https://serverfault.com/questions/30705/how-to-set-up-nginx-as-a-caching-reverse-proxy)